# Access custom Model in Refinery PagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I integrated RefineryCMS to my existing Application, but how do I access my existing models in the refinery pages controller.
Want to display a sign-up form on the frontpage so I have to create a new User.

I tried this:

```
 Refinery::PagesController.class_eval do

        before_filter :create_new_user, :only => [:home]

        protected

          def create_new_user
            @user = User.new
          end

     end
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the error message. Try `::User.new` to access the default main namespace. By the way, Refinery comes with `Refinery::User` so you could use that as your user model.